# Returning Unique Values in Acess database with several columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Been googling this for hours now. But can't find a way to make my sql query work.

```
SELECT barn.förnamn+' '+barn.efternamn AS Child, målsman.förnamn+' '+målsman.efternamn AS Parent, Målsman.postnummer
FROM barn INNER JOIN Målsman ON barn.Postnummer = Målsman.Postnummer
WHERE (((Målsman.postnummer) Like '*23*'));
```

I have two tables. `Målsman` and `Barn`. This is tables with children in one and parents in one. Both of these have the columns; `Förnamn`, `Efternamn` and `Postnummer`.
Now some of these kids have the same parent and some of the parents also have two kids. This results in two kids with the same "`postnummer`" and two parents with the same "`postnummer`". So when I do this query my result comes back with duplicates.

Is it a problem with the way I have made this database or can I change my query to not get duplicates. I've tried with `Distinct` but does not seem to work and I have heard somewhere that you can use order by or group by. Do not understand that.

So any suggestions would be appreciated. :)

The output I get from running this is

[Picture of the result](http://i50.tinypic.com/2ivtle.png)

So I don't want the same child to appear several times

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your data, but I think you need to add GROUP BY barn.förnamn+' '+barn.efternamn, målsman.förnamn+' '+målsman.efternamn, Målsman.postnummer after the WHERE clause to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Step 1 is to know what you want.  If you have two kids with the same postnummer, which one do you want?

Comment: Sorry for that. have tried that group by before and it just returns the same result. Maybe i can change everything to english so it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Don't worry about the language.  It's easy to understand.

Comment: I have now updated with a link to a picture. Cant post pictures here since i am new =/  @DanBracuk

Comment: The picture shows what you are getting but doesn't show what you would like to get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not totally clear. But to associate only one parent to a particular child you might try something like:

```
SELECT Child, MIN(Parent) AS Parent, postnummer FROM (
SELECT barn.förnamn+' '+barn.efternamn AS Child, målsman.förnamn+' '+målsman.efternamn AS Parent, Målsman.postnummer as postnummer
FROM barn INNER JOIN Målsman ON barn.Postnummer = Målsman.Postnummer
WHERE (((Målsman.postnummer) Like '*23*'))
) a
GROUP BY child, postnummer
```

Comment: Hm, It says i cant have a * in the select form when using group

Comment: Im trying to get it to work. It just says (freely translated from swedish) Your query did not contain the expression Parent as part of a aggreate function

Comment: Well, this worked like a charm. What was it that made it now work ??

Comment: We cannot print parent before because it data are aggregated BY child, postnummer so min apeared

Comment: Aha, Is there any way to make the MIN(Parent) show up as Parent and not EXPR1001 in the column after runing the query?

Comment: Sure. Done. I hope you have looked for something like that. GL!

Comment: So. now its solved! This is what i ended up with and it works very well! SELECT a.Barn, Min(a.Målsman) AS Målsman, a.postnummer
FROM (SELECT barn.förnamn+' '+barn.efternamn AS Barn, målsman.förnamn+' '+målsman.efternamn AS Målsman, Målsman.postnummer as postnummer
FROM barn INNER JOIN Målsman ON barn.Postnummer = Målsman.Postnummer
WHERE (((Målsman.postnummer) Like '*23*'))
)  AS a
GROUP BY a.Barn, a.postnummer;